# How to tell if a managed package is running on the govCloud or not?

Tags: apex, govcloud

Background: I am developing a managed package and want to make my package available to govcloud orgs/users. However, I need to have my package reach out to a different URL on my side of things if it is a govcloud instance.

Is there a reliable way to determine if a given org that my managed package is installed on is a govcloud org? I haven't been able to find anything with looking at documentation.